# Handling POST to req.body in Node.js & Express using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, post

I'm using Ajax in my Node.js & Express website in order to send a value from a text box to the server side.
Right now, it is working; the req.body has the text value that I need, however the JSON is formatted in a way that is difficult for me to get the value. In short, it seems my ajax is renaming the variable name to the value entered within the text box. So instead of the req.body being

```
{ hashtag: 'test123' }
```

The req.body shows:

```
{ test123: '' }
```

E.g:
In my Jade file:

```
         form
            input#hash(type='text', name='hashtag[hash]', placeholder='#Hashtag')
            input#submit.btn.btn-primary(name='submit', type='submit', value='Send', onclick='return chk()')

    p#msg


script.
  function chk(){
    var posthash = document.getElementById('hashtag').value;
    console.log(posthash);
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "/api/hash",
        data:posthash,
        cache:false,
        success: function(html){
            console.log("Successfully posted");
            $('#msg').html(html);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
  return false;
  }
```

Then, within my server.js:

```
app.post("/api/hash", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

So, if I enter this into the text box:

> test123

The req.body shows:

```
{ test123: '' }
```

As you can see, the variable name itself is the value of the text box. Thus, if I try to say **console.log(req.body.hashtag)** or **console.log(req.body.hash)**, it comes up as undefined - because that's not the variable name.

Comment: `console.log(posthash);` prints properly?

Comment: @AndreaM16 Yes, if I change `document.getElementById('hashtag')` to  `document.getElementById('hash')` it prints properly. At the moment, `document.getElementById('hashtag')` doesn't actually work, as it can't find that value for some reason... I changed it to hashtag to test

Comment: To me it seems like your post is fine but you are sending an empty string. Try taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you submit the `posthash`. This variable contains the string you enter in the input,but `$.ajax` is expecting an object as `data` option. Just change the line like this :

```
 data: {hashtag: posthash} ,
```

And since you declare the input with `hash` as id

```
input#hash
```

you have to use

```
document.getElementById('hash').value;
```

to get it's value.